# Having issues with LibMan

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

Trying to add JqueryUI to my project to incorporate the new date picker.

I go to "Add client-side library" and it opens the LibMan panel.

However, when I try to pull in `jqueryuo@1.12.1` I get

> "Failed to download catalog from provider "cdnjs".

Anyone else experienced this?

Is there another way to add and reference the JQueryUI library?

I am using `VS 2017 Community edition V15.9.9` with `.Net Core 2.1` framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely available on cdnjs, so I'm assuming your typo must be actually in your project and not a result of writing your question. You have `jqueryuo`, not `jqueryui`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry it was a typo in my question, not in the library I try to add.

I definitely try to pull in "jqueryui@1.12.1"

I also get the error "cannot find library in provider "cdnjs""

Comment: Maybe you are behind a proxy, check if you are able to connect to internet via vs2017, do you need to set a proxy for libman? refer to https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/399